# C parsing double from argument strings

Tags: c, parsing, arguments

I'm trying to parse an argument value in C and convert the number to a double value.  I have:

`char *stringEnd;
double num = strtod("123.0", &stringEnd);`

I used `"123.0"` just to test the function, but it always returns a value of `0.0`.  Does anybody know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: this looks ok, must be somewhere else.  maybe show us more code?

Comment: Don't forget the memory management on stringEnd, right now, it points at whatever value the memory holds.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Are you including the relevant header? ie: [`#include <stdlib.h>`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strtod)

First though (and you should be doing this all the time anyway), try compiling with all warnings on (`-Wall` on GCC).

If you get a warning about `strtod` being undefined, that shows where the problem is coming from.

This is a nasty one, because C will implicitly declare any function it doesn't have a prototype for as returning `int`!

Comment: hmm, why the downvote?  I'm pretty sure this is the correct answer.  Oh well.

Comment: Not quite: it implicitly takes it as returning an int, not 0. But you're asking the same question I would...

Comment: It implicitly *declares* it as returning int. The definition isn't implicit: it's actually calling the library function, the correct definition with the wrong declaration. Hence looking in the wrong place for the return value — an integer register instead of an FP register.

Comment: In this case, the returned value is 0.0 because eax is set to zero on entry and the actual value is stored on a floating point register. It could be worse if floating point and integer were stored in the same registers.

Comment: @Darius  Ah sorry yeah, I meant to type returns int, not 0 - wrote that in a hurry on the way out of the door.  Correcting now.

Comment: Awesome. I thought this was included in the string.h library, but clearly I was wrong.  Thanks a lot.

Comment: The `-Wall` flag is very useful! It just helped me spot the fact that I was trying to use `atof()` w/o including `stdlib.h`. My program compiled and ran w/o `stdlib.h`???, but it behaved strangely. Thanks!

Comment: @PeterAjtai it would have compiled for the reason I said in my answer - C (but not C++) will implicitly declare any function it doesn't have a prototype for.  This is for historical reasons.

Answer (score 3):

You if have to use [`strtod`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdlib/strtod/) in order to use:

```
double num = strtod("123.0", NULL);
```

you can also use [`sscanf`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/sscanf/)

```
double num;    
sscanf("123.0", "%lf", &num);
```

Comment: -1. You're repeating his code, except not allowing a way to detect errors (that's what the second parameter to strtod is for) and exactly repeating an earlier (though only by 2 minutes) answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `sscanf`.

```
double num;
sscanf("123.0", "%lf", &num);
```

Comment: Unless you're trying to parse multiple items from one string, there's no benefit to using `sscanf` over `strtod`.  It's more complicated and has the drawback of making it harder to detect malformed data.

Answer (score 1):

You need to `#include stdlib.h`.

Answer (score 0):

In which language is your operating system? I'm not sure how the C function strtod reacts, but I know that the equivalent delphi function takes the settings of the operating system into account. Some languages (french, german, ...) use a "," instead of a "." as decimal separator.